# Facebook canvas app authentication redirects to my domain

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-authentication

I tried several approaches, for eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989194/facebook-app-getting-redirected-out-canvas-view) with no luck. I'm using their [facebook php sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk).

What happens now is that the app gets redirected to my site after getting authenticated.

```
<?php 
require_once 'php-sdk/facebook.php';
$app_id = "***";
$app_secret = "***";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'=> $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if(!$user)
{
    $auth_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
}
?>
```

I tried replacing auth_url with:

```
$auth_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email',
'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/ridetogether'));
```

but the prompt told me that the redirect_url is not owned by me:

An error occurred with Ride Together. Please try again later.

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

What else can I do to just redirect back to the canvas app inside facebook?

Comment: What values are you getting from $auth_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email')); ?

Comment: it's a settings problem, check your app settings on Facebook. If you aren't using Facebook's official php sdk, then please switch to that.

Answer (score 1):

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Is your namespace/canvas page correct at your application setting? You might have to double check that again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a specific page on your domain to redirect to, like this

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'email',
  'redirect_uri' => $authPageURL,
);

$auth_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Then that page needs to redirect to your canvas URL using a 301. So create a page called auth.php or something that has this in it

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['error_reason']))
{
    header('Location: '.$auth_error_page);
}
else 
{       
    header('Location: '.$FB_canvas_page);
}
```

Then use that page as the redirect URI.

Comment: Theres no way to just redirect inside the iFrame canvas?

Comment: What is the exact behaviour that you are after? It looks like you are attempting to authenticate with the server side flow on first load of the app, and then subsequent requests to the app does something with the users data. If you redirect from your auth page to your canvas page your content will appear with in the iframe on your app page. The server side flow will break out of the iframe for the authentication step.